# Password verification help PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm new to PHP, just playing around with it on the side whilst at university.  I've decided to make a guild webpage for WoW and am having issues wrapping my head around some concepts.  Mainly the following.

```
$res=mysqli_query("SELECT userId, userName, userPass FROM users WHERE userEmail='$email'");
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($res);
```

To my understanding the variable, $count, should be 1 here.  It connects to the database ok and my signup page adds details into the tables so I know all of that is working.

Just for simplicity's sake, there is only 1 entry in the database.  There are only 3 columns, userId userName and userPass.  But for some reason the following if statement returns false and does the else.

```
if($count == 1)
```

Anyone able to explain how sql results into arrays works?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: so you want to compare the password with a variable ? try to test with "printf ("%s (%s)\n",$row[0],$row[1]);"

Comment: It would help you if you read the manual regarding the functions you are using on php.net. You need to learn what each does / returns etc.In your case http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: `"To my understanding the variable, $count, should be 1 here..."` ...  Well, that depends. For the assumption to be true, then the `userEmail` column must be unique so that only one entry can exist, otherwise, the count could be more. You can also use `var_dump($row);` to output the row data.

Answer (score 5):

There is an issue with your query if what you write about only having 3 columns is correct.

However, you should learn to dump your variables to see what they actually contain. This will help you debug your code. Check what `$row` contains by writing `var_dump($row);` and the same with `var_dump($count)`.

And if it is as you say, only 3 columns in your database: `userId` `userName` and `userPass`, then `userEmail` won't get any matches, since there is no column actually named `userEmail`

Comment: I did the var_dumps and saw that it wasn't working at all, and as you said, it was an issue with userEmail not being a valid field.  That was probably because I have tried this in different files and mixed two up.  The main issue though I believe was the lack of a link.

Answer (score 3):

As you are using mysqli you need to define the connection at the begining of the first statement - it should read something like:

```
$res=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT userId, userName, userPass 
FROM users WHERE userEmail='$email'");
```

Comment: It should be noted that if you are using mysqli, you should also be using prepared statements for the query in this example to prevent sql injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: The prepared statements was done prior to this bit, I'd read about SQL injection and overcame that with the help of a friend, but on the subject of needing the connection definition; that was the true nature of the issue I believe as after I added that it all sprung into life.  Thank you!!

Comment: Glad it solved your problem - you can click the arrow to the left to mark this as the accepted answer. FYI if you are using the above code then I do not believe you are using prepared statements - you may well have come up with a way of "overcoming" SQL injection but prepared statements will always be the best route.